# How to insert iframe in our website the metamask registration?

Tags: web3js, metamask

How to insert iframe in our website the metamask registration? We want to input a registration form of metamask in our website without redirecting in other page.

Comment: Metamask is an add on to the browser or a mobile app. There is no registration per say beside providing a seed phrase to generate the wallet. So what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What will be your suggestion for us to want a metamask registration in our website page?

Comment: Your technically asking me how you can override metamask registration to get the user private key?

Comment: No, we want to input the metamask registration FORM in our website for the users to register metamask account within our website page only.

Comment: You mean a connect button?? You want to connect the wallet with your app?

Comment: The pop-up that is asking you to connect the wallet?

Comment: Maybe, so how to do that has a metamask registration button and to redirect to pop-up?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able achieve this.
Metamask is providing your browser with a web3 module that you can use to connect your app to the blockchain.

The users will be able to connect to your app to sign transaction.

In order to connect your app to the blockchain, you will need web3 or ethersjs.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/getting-started.html

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/

This is how we make decentralized app that are connected to the blockchain.
You should also look at infura for a provider.

https://infura.io/

The Providers are access point where Metamask is connected to and send transaction to.

When you want to connect to a Provider without Metamask. You have to use Infura directly. Metamask is convenient on the front end because it is the provider for the client. Otherwise you need to provide a Provider to connect to.

You can also create a wallet within your app. Generate a seed and use this seed in metamask or use it only for your app and use another Provider.

If you want the wallet to work only on your "site". It will have to be managed in a centralized manner and you will provide everything.

The wallet, The Provider and the back-end infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer and guide.